# Convert Magento1 Text Attribute to magento2 PriceType Attribute

Tags: attributes, conversion

Looking for solution for converting some attributes to another type.

Problem:

We sell boxes with dimensions Length, width, height on Magento 1 webshop.
On the frontend in Layered Navigation we used size Sliders for this attributes.

For this atrributes we used the type with Catalog Input Type for Store Owner --> 
"Text"

All fields where fidlled with millimeters (Only the numeric values, not mm).

Now we want to change this 3 attributes from 'text' to 'Price', since all Layered navigation extensions require the input type "Price" field to get this attributes working with sliders.

Who can help?
Any idea how much work this takes?
Or maybe yo have a better solution?

I found an old script which should do the trick but this one needs a rewrite.